# How to represent the given information correctly to solve for a particular solution to a differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Lupita's lawn is left unattended so that an infestation of weeds begins to take over. The rate of growth of the weeds is proportional to the area of lawn not yet invaded by weeds.

a) If $W \space m^2$ is the area of lawn taken over by weeds after t weeks, and the lawn has a total area of $A \space m^2$, write the differential equation that models the situation.

b) The area taken over by weeds grows from one quarter to one half the total area of the lawn in $T$ weeks. If $t = 0$ when $W = \frac{1}{4}A$, solve the differential euqation in part a).

First I write down the differential equation, which is: $\frac{dW}{dt} = k(A - W)$. I proceed and find the general solution for this differential equation which is: $W = A - Be^{-kt}$ for that I let $e^c = B$
.

I continue this with the information I know to interpret; that is when $t = 0$,  $W = \frac{1}{4}A$.

This gives:
$\frac{1}{4}A = A - Be^{-k(0)}$

$\frac{3}{4}A = B$. Substituting this back to the equation:

$W = A - \frac{3}{4}Ae^{-kt}$

**Now this is where I am stuck. I am unsure how to represent** "The area taken over by weeds grows from one quarter to one half the total area of the lawn in $T$ weeks" **mathematically.** I have the proportional constant $k$ left to solve.

Do I have to do something like:$ \int _{\frac{1}{4}A}^{\frac{1}{2}A}\:\frac{1}{A-W}dW\:=\:\int _0^T\:k\:dt$ How can I solve for $k$, hence the equation?

FYI the answer is:
$W\:=\:A\:-\frac{3}{4}Ae^{ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)t}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are first $T$ weeks (since the initial condition is $W_0 = \frac{1}{4} A$), you have:

$$ \frac{1}{4} A = A(1-\frac{3}{4} e^{k*0}) $$

and

$$ \frac{1}{2} A = A (1-\frac{3}{4} e^{k*T}) $$

Dividing the second one with the first one:

$$\begin{align}
 2 &= \frac{(1-\frac{3}{4} e^{kT})}{(1-\frac{3}{4} e^{k*0})} \\
1 &= 2 - 2 \frac{3}{4} e^{kT} \\
\frac{1}{2} &= \frac{3}{4} e^{kT} \\
\ln(\frac{2}{3}) &= kT \\
k &= \frac{\ln(\frac{2}{3})}{T}
\end{align} $$

Comment: But the answer is $W\:=\:A\:-\frac{3}{4}Ae^{ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)t}$

Comment: They could have missed the $T$. Note that it makes sense you get something of the form $\frac{t}{T}$ in order to be dimentionless.

Comment: What does dimensionless means?

Comment: Dimentionless means that it has no units. For example, $W$ and $A$ have units of area, $t$ of time, etc.. In the other hand, $\frac{3}{4}$ is dimentionless. It's useful to see if you made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

> Lupita's lawn is left unattended so that an infestation of weeds begins to take over. The rate of growth of the weeds is proportional to the area of lawn not yet invaded by weeds.

> (a) If $W \space m^2$ is the area of lawn taken over by weeds after $\color{red}{t_0}$ weeks, and the lawn has a total area of $A \space m^2$, write the differential equation that models the situation.

> (b) The area taken over by weeds grows from one quarter to one half the total area of the lawn in $T$ weeks. If $t = 0$ when $W = \frac{1}{4}A$, solve the differential equation in part (a).

Let $x\equiv x(t)$ be the area covered by weeds at any time $t$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac {dx}{dt}&=k(A-x)\\
x&=A-B\exp\left({-kt}\right)\\
W&=A-B\exp\left({-kt_0}\right)\\
x&=A-(A-W)\exp\left({-k(t-t_0)}\right)\\
\frac{A-x}{A-W}&=\exp\left({-k(t-t_0)}\right)\\
\frac{A-\frac A4}{A-W}&=\exp\left({-k(t_1-t_0)}\right)\tag{1}\\
\frac{A-\frac A2}{A-W}&=\exp\left({-k(t_2-t_0)}\right)\tag{2}\\
\frac32&=\exp\left({k(t_2-t_1)}\right)&(\because\text{Dividing }(1)\text{ by }(2))\\
\frac32&=\exp\left({kT}\right)\\
\frac{\ln\left(\frac32\right)}T&=k\\
\Rightarrow x&=A-(A-W)\exp\left[{-\ln\left(\frac32\right)\left(\frac{t-t_0}T\right)}\right]\\
\Rightarrow \frac A4&=A-(A-W)\exp\left[{\frac{t_0}T\ln\left(\frac32\right)}\right]\\
\frac{3A}{4(A-W)}&=\exp\left[{\frac{t_0}T\ln\left(\frac32\right)}\right]\\
\ln\left(\frac{3A}{4(A-W)}\right)&=\frac{t_0}T\ln\left(\frac32\right)\\
\Rightarrow x&=A-(A-W)\exp\left[{-\ln\left(\frac32\right)\left(\dfrac{t-\frac{T\ln\left(\frac{3A}{4(A-W)}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac32\right)}}T\right)}\right]\\
x&=A-(A-W)\exp\left[\ln\left(\frac{3A}{4(A-W)}\right)-\ln\left(\frac32\right)\frac tT\right]\\
x&=A-(A-W)\exp\left[\ln\left(\frac{3A}{4(A-W)}\right)\right]\exp\left[-\ln\left(\frac32\right)\frac tT\right]\\
x&=A-\frac{3A}4\exp\left[\ln\left(\frac23\right)\frac tT\right]&\left(\because -\ln\left(\frac ab\right)=\ln\left(\frac ba\right)\right)\\
x&=A-\frac{3A}4\left(\frac32\right)^{-\dfrac tT}&(\because \exp\left(\ln x\right)=x)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi Sameer, is this complete? I arrived here, but there are still 2 variables? Can you format it into a particular solution?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk I don't think it is possible to eliminate $T$. What do you think?

Comment: I have no idea, my textbook give $W\:=\:A\:-\frac{3}{4}Ae^{ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)t}$

Comment: It appears that $T$ is eliminated from the given answer

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk My answer is correct because exponents are always dimensionless. There is a typo in your book.

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk You can check the same by putting $t=T$ in your book's and my answer. You should get $x\rvert_{_T}=\frac A2$. If you are satisfied, perhaps you can approve my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But what does dimensionless means?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk $t$ has the [dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#The_factor-label_method_for_converting_units) of time. $\exp(\alpha t)$, where $\alpha$ is *dimensionless*, does not make sense because when you put $t=1$sec (say), it becomes $\exp(\alpha\cdot1\text{ sec})$. How can someone evaluate the factor $\exp(1\text{ sec})$? Providing $\exp(\alpha \frac{t}T)$, where $T$ also has the dimensions of time, seems legit.

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk Another possibility is that your book considers $t$ as the number of weeks, hence dimensionless. **Nevertheless, $T$ must be there in the answer, regardless of dimensions, as putting $t=T$ suggests.** Forget the whole dimension thing if you are not comfortable with it.

Comment: Right thank you.

Comment: @Sameer Baheti, $t$ is in "weeks" already. Being a number of weeks doesn't make it dimentionless. Being a ratio between 2 magnitudes in units of time does.